# Merging lines of one feature class from pair coordinates with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, coordinates, merge

```
cursor=arcpy.da.searchCursor("mettaled", "SHAPE@")
for row in cursor:
    geom=row[0]
    for part in geom:
        for pnt in part:
        x,y=pnt.X, pnt.Y
        print x,y
```

I am trying to merge the intersected line together(one feature class), but the problem is that some of those line having gaps and not intersected 100%.
note: I used to do it with 'unsplit line' then 'spatial join' but that didn't work with gaped lines.

Can anyone do that with **arcpy**
like list coordinates of the lines and connect-append the end point with the start of the next line

[image: example of only two line]

Comment: What happened when you ran the code that you’ve presented?

Comment: Looking over your code, it appears you have a multi-part polyline that you want to convert into a single-part polyline (which involves removing the gap).  Is that correct?

Comment: @PolyGeo it bring the x,y of all the line vertex

Comment: exactly that's what am looking for @bixb0012

Answer (score 0):

What will work in this situation since the parts are inline with each other is to take the points from each part and create a new, single ArcPy array and pass that to the Polyline constructor to create a new single-part polyline.

```py
>>> import arcpy
>>> 
>>> install_info = arcpy.GetInstallInfo()
>>> f"{install_info['ProductName']}, {install_info['Version']}"
'ArcGISPro, 2.9.1'
>>> 
>>> # illustrative code for combining multi-part polyline to single-part polyline
>>> multi_polyline = arcpy.FromWKT('MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 2 0, 2 1, 4 1),(8 2, 10 2, 12 4))')
>>> multi_polyline.isMultipart
True
>>> multi_polyline.partCount
2
>>>
>>> single_polyline = arcpy.Polyline(
...     arcpy.Array([vertex for part in multi_polyline for vertex in part])
... )
>>> single_polyline.isMultipart
False
>>> single_polyline.partCount
1
>>>
>>> # modified OP code to combine multi-part polyline to single-part polyline
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("mettaled", "SHAPE@") as cur:
    for shape, in cur:  # notice the comma after shape for tuple unpacking
        new_shape = arcpy.Polyline(
            arcpy.Array([vertex for part in shape for vertex in part]),
            shape.spatialReference
        )
        cur.updateRow([new_shape])
        
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but am beginner at python so if you don't mind can you clarify it more? like if I need to change any of the Parameter or any thing else

Comment: @saraghafri, I updated my code block to include modifications to your code that should work.